# Android Studio has several errors when started a new project

Tags: android-studio

I just launched Android Studio, started a project and everything my eyes can see has a red line drawn beneath even the names of files. I did not change anything at all just launched android studio started a new project and I get errors everywhere. is there something missing from the files?

[image]

Tried re-opening the app and syncing the Gradle expected that maybe Gradle sync might fix it but the errors are still there

Here are the errors:

```
Unresolved reference: os :3
Cannot access 'android.app.Activity' which is a supertype of 'com.example.greetingcard.MainActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies :15
Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'com.example.greetingcard.MainActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies :15
Unresolved reference: Bundle :16
Cannot access 'android.app.Activity' which is a supertype of 'com.example.greetingcard.MainActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies :17
Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'com.example.greetingcard.MainActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies :17
Cannot access 'android.app.Activity' which is a supertype of 'androidx.activity.ComponentActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies :17
Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'androidx.activity.ComponentActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies :17
Cannot access class 'android.os.Bundle'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies :17
Cannot access 'android.app.Activity' which is a supertype of 'androidx.activity.ComponentActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies :18
Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'androidx.activity.ComponentActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies :18
```

Comment: Have you installed a platform and SDK tools? Tools menu, SDK manager. This ought to have been covered by the install setup wizard though.

Comment: @Rup I thought Android studio took care of that it even downloaded some files when I started the Gradle sync but I still don't know why it throws errors